# Fitting data to function with loop built in

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a program which calculates value of R (reflectivity) from series of matrices... but I know that one of n values (n3 which is reflection index) was just guessed. Now I would like use defined function to go through different n3 values to find the best fit R(l) to my data (they are stored in separated file). I tried to play with optimization.curve_fit but honestly I don't have idea how to properly use it in this case since R, which corresponds to "y" is generated by 2 loops and not a real function...

```
from scipy import*
from scipy import linalg
import math
import cmath
from numpy import linalg
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimization

infile=open('C:\Users\...\Data.txt', 'r')

n0=1. 
n1=2.31
n2=2. 
n3=1.8
d1=20*10**(-9)
d2=20*10**(-9)

lmin=700*10**(-9)
lmax=2200*10**(-9)
dl=1*10**(-9)
l=lmin

Theta=0

D0=matrix([[math.cos(math.radians(Theta)), math.cos(math.radians(Theta))],[n0, -n0]], dtype=complex)
D1=matrix([[math.cos(math.radians(Theta)), math.cos(math.radians(Theta))],[n1, -n1]], dtype=complex)
D2=matrix([[math.cos(math.radians(Theta)), math.cos(math.radians(Theta))],[n2, -n2]], dtype=complex)



Fi1= 0+0j
Fi2= 0+0j


P1=matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=complex)
P2=matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=complex)

M=matrix([[1,0],[0,1]], dtype=complex)

R=0+0j
r=0+0j

#File reading
x,y = numpy.loadtxt('C:\Users\...\Data.txt',dtype=float).transpose()


DL = []
Res = []

#Funcion
def R(l):
        l=lmin
        D3=matrix([[math.cos(math.radians(Theta)), math.cos(math.radians(Theta))],[n3, -n3]], dtype=complex)
        while l<lmax:
                Fi1= 2.* pi * n1 *d1 * math.cos(math.radians(Theta))/l
                Fi2= 2.* pi * n2 *d2 * math.cos(math.radians(Theta))/l
                f1 = math.e**(1j*Fi1)
                f2 = math.e**(1j*Fi2)
                P1 = matrix([[1/f1, 0], [0, f1]])
                P2 = matrix([[1/f2, 0], [0, f2]])
                T=matrix([[1,0],[0,1]], dtype=complex)
                for i in range(0,9): 
                        T=D1*P1*(D1)**(-1)*D2*P2*(D2)**(-1)*T
                M=D0**(-1)*T*D3
                r=M[1,0]/M[0,0]
                R=abs(M[1,0]/M[0,0])**2
                Res.append(R)
                DL.append(l)
                l=l+dl



        return R

#print optimization.curve_fit(R(l), x, y)

R(l)


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(DL,Res)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can load x,y from Data.txt doing:  `x,y = numpy.loadtxt('Data.txt',dtype=float).transpose()`... It would clean your question. Also, why your function `f()` returns `n3`?

Comment: Thank you for advice (I applied your file reading code). I trided to show python that n3 is adjustable parameter... this was just a try (of course one of many not working tries)

Comment: do you want to fit x and y with some function and compare to DL and Res?

Comment: Do you mean doing my own "least squares" code (fitting something to x an y-> fitting something to DL and Res->comparing->changing n3->fitting->...)? Hmm... not sure if in some point fitting errors will not break n3 value. Would be easier if Python could work with symbols then I could get flexible analitical equation for R (from 2 elements of matrix M) and then try to fit R(l) using x and y data and adjustable parameter n3

Comment: indeed Python can work with symbols. [take a look in SymPy](http://sympy.rg/en/index.html)

Comment: Wow, this is great news. Thank you! (hope I will be able to use it;)

Comment: Looks like analitical way is not a good solution... There is no error but Python Shell is just crashing (too many matrices to count?). But nice to know that symbols can be used